# Which Theano for PyMC3?

Tags: python-3.x, theano, pymc3

> Disclaimer: SO is forcing me to express stdout output copied below as code. Simple quoting wouldn't allow me to post

I have a pyproject.toml file from a Proof of Concept that worked beautifully a few months ago, which includes:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]  
theano = "^1.0.5"  
pymc3 = "^3.9.3"
```

I copied this over to start extending from the Proof of Concept, and when trying to run it I get

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!  
The installed Theano(-PyMC) version (1.0.5) does not match the PyMC3 requirements.  
For PyMC3 to work, Theano must be uninstalled and replaced with Theano-PyMC.  
See https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/wiki for installation instructions.  
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

So I followed instructions -- removed theano and added Theano-PyMC3. *This* gave me no big alert at the beginning of the output, but failed:

```
File "mycode.py", line 4, in <module>
    import pymc3
File "/home/user/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/project-xNaK0WN7-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymc3/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    if not semver.match(theano.__version__, ">=1.1.2"):
AttributeError: module 'theano' has no attribute '__version__'
```

I then tried adding aesara with a just-try-it scattergun mentality, and got the same error. I tried adding stock theano again on top of all the above, and got the first error again, even with Theano-PyMC3 still installed, and the Traceback ends with:

```
File "/home/user/.../code.py", line 4, in <module>  
    import pymc3  
File "/home/user/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/project-xNaK0WN7-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymc3/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>  
    __set_compiler_flags()  
File "/home/user/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/project-xNaK0WN7-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymc3/__init__.py", line 46, in __set_compiler_flags  
    current = theano.config.gcc__cxxflags  
AttributeError: 'TheanoConfigParser' object has no attribute 'gcc__cxxflags'
```

Why would the same version pymc3 that worked just fine with theano last time now have a problem with it? The link provided (https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/wiki) in the !!!! alert is virtually blank, so not helpful.

Comment: Does `theano` even need to be explicitly specified? It should come in as a dependency to `pymc3`. Also, note that the package is `theano-pymc` (without the "3"). It worked before because 3.9.3 used `theano` and `3.10` released, using the newer version; you provided a lower bound, so likely installed at least 3.10. The link has installation guide links in the menu on the side.

Comment: @merv, yes, inspecting poetry.lock, in the Proof of Concept from a few months ago, it was 3.9.3 that got installed. In the most recent `poetry install`, it grabbed 3.11.2. Evidently it's the latest version that has a theano problem -- requiring >=1.1.2, which I can't see exists.

I did finally get a working config by forcing installation of pymc3 3.10.0 (by omitting the caret), theano-pymc3 = "^1.0.11" (1.0.11 installed per poetry.lock), and also needed to fix a subsequent arviz problem with explicit `arviz = "0.11.0" (again, no caret). A workaround, I think, not a real solution.